# Asp MVC load report failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I am trying to use crystal report with asp mvc first time but I have some problem to load report:

```
ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();
            rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("Reports/TestReport.rpt");
            rptH.Load();
```

This is value of rptH.FileName

```
"rassdk://D:\\ProjectDir\\Pro\\Pro.WebUI\\Reports\\TestReport.rpt"
```

But on `Load()` I get exception:

> Load report failed.

Report doesn't have any datasource it's just blank report with some text.
Maybe it's important. I set project to run on **local IIS** (not in VS).

**UPDATE**

I have changed code a little bit and now I get some other error (I also copied project in inetpub/wwwroot). This is the error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path2

And path now is:

```
"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\MyProject\\Pro\\Pro.WebUI\\Reports\\TestReport.rpt"
```

New code is:

```
ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();
            var path = Server.MapPath("Reports/TestReport.rpt");

            rptH.Load(path);
```

Comment: Can somebody at least suggest where can I look for problem. I don't have any idea any more.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a Crystal Report with ASP.NET before.  Not sure if you're able to do this or not, but it worked successfully for me.

```
 ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
 rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("TestReport.rpt");

 Response.Buffer = False
 Response.ClearContent()
 Response.ClearHeaders()

 rptDoc.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "TestReport.rpt")
 rptDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "MyReport")
```

Comment: Should I add some security role on project in inetpub or something like that it's wired? If I put report url in browser It download me .rpt file. So path is good. But application can't find it :(

Comment: What do you want to do with it?  Display right there on demand in the browser?

Comment: I added a few lines.  The document object has several different options on exporting the report.  Check out these two and the other options as well maybe.

Comment: I want to export it to PDF. I tried what you suggest but I always what ever I do I get `Load report failed.`

Answer (score 0):

Check the rpt file if there are parameters defined.
If there are and you do not need them then remove it.
If you need them then supply them values and description in code.
Exp:

```
rep = new ReportDocument();
string reportPath = Server.MapPath("Reports/TestReport.rpt");
rep.Load(reportPath);
rep.SetParameterValue(0, "SomeValue");
crViewer.ReportSource = rep;
crViewer.ParameterFieldInfo[0].CurrentValues[0].Description = "ParameterName";
crViewer.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
  string FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Report") + "//YourReportName.rpt";
  rd.Load(FileName);
  rd.SetDataSource(dt);
```